# Including CSS, Javascript with my Laravel 4 framework

Tags: php, laravel

I have included a `_construct()` function into my BaseController to include CSS and Javascript using the Asset::add command.  However, the CSS doesn't seem to be loading in.  The view is loading correctly (so I know there are no errors or exceptions being thrown), but the CSS is not being applied.

For one view, I have:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="banner-image"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the CSS, banner-image is defined as:

```
.banner-image{background:transparent url(/assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg) no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;background-size:cover; height:800px; min-width: 1200px;}
```

I have the assets folder inside my public folder.

However, the image is not loading on the page (the page remains blank).  Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you dumped the assets in the header anywhere??

like this...

```
   <head>
     {{Asset::styles();}}
   </head>
```

But I think that only works with Laravel 3....

It is my understanding that assets are called differently in L4

Anyway....

I just echo them directly into my header views...Like so...

```
echo asset('css/yourcssfile.css');
```

or, if you're using Blade templating..

```
{{asset('css/yourcssfile.css')}}
```

Also...assuming your css folder is directly in the public folder like public/css
Then the path to your image background would change to this...

```
.banner-image{background:transparent url('../assets/images/hires_080820-F-5957S-987c.jpg') no-repeat center center;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;background-size:cover; height:800px; min-width: 1200px;}
```

Because you need to get out of the css folder, so you apply ../

Also it's good to put single quotes around paths

Comment: It says "Class 'Asset' not found" when I include the head like that.  Ideas?

Comment: also, for the echo, where do you put the echo??

Comment: Yeah it says that because Laravel 4 doesn't have that class anymore.....so you would put that echo in the <head> </head> of your header page.....if you have a header page....or just in the <head></head> tag of that page if you dont have a predefined header

Comment: Do you know what I mean?  So remove the Asset::Add call from your constructor__

Answer (score 0):

Place the css and js files in the public folder, then load in them as the name.blade.php files are in the public folder too.